# Is there a distinguishing characteristic of a 'contract creation' transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, receipts

Look at this transaction:

> https://etherscan.io/tx/0x37c469573ca24f538d91f39e9d0b8d49927a36d70496ef74521cbf5c44a056d4

In geth's console, if I enter:

> eth.getTransaction('0x37c4...')

It returns the transaction with a `to` value of `null`.  I'm pretty sure this is because this transaction is a contract deployment.

If I look at:

> eth.getTransactionReceipt('0x37c4...')

with the same transaction id, the `contract address` field is non-empty.

My question: is `to` being `null` enough to distinguish a transaction as one that deployed a contract? And secondly, is looking at the receipt the only way to get the address of the contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q** is `to` being `null` enough to distinguish a transaction as one that deployed a contract?

Yes

**Q** is looking at the receipt the only way to get the address of the contract?

Yes, in the go-ethereum client. <strike>, although you can probably work out the contract address from the trace results of the `debug.traceTransaction(...)` API call as well.</strike>

EDIT: I searched through the `debug.traceTransaction(...)` results and could not find the created contract address.

---

From the go-ethereum source code [eth/api.go, lines 481-504](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/3885907c7deb598ed491ca4deccc562b27b31d66/eth/api.go#L481-L504) that follows, you can see that the condition where the `To` address is `nil` is used to decide whether the transaction is a contract creation transaction:

```
func (s *PrivateAccountAPI) SignAndSendTransaction(args SendTxArgs, passwd string) (common.Hash, error) {
    args = prepareSendTxArgs(args, s.gpo)

    s.txMu.Lock()
    defer s.txMu.Unlock()

    if args.Nonce == nil {
        args.Nonce = rpc.NewHexNumber(s.txPool.State().GetNonce(args.From))
    }

    var tx *types.Transaction
    if args.To == nil {
        tx = types.NewContractCreation(args.Nonce.Uint64(), args.Value.BigInt(), args.Gas.BigInt(), args.GasPrice.BigInt(), common.FromHex(args.Data))
    } else {
        tx = types.NewTransaction(args.Nonce.Uint64(), *args.To, args.Value.BigInt(), args.Gas.BigInt(), args.GasPrice.BigInt(), common.FromHex(args.Data))
    }

    signature, err := s.am.SignWithPassphrase(args.From, passwd, tx.SigHash().Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return common.Hash{}, err
    }

    return submitTransaction(s.txPool, tx, signature)
}
```

This is confirmed in **4.3 The Transaction** in the [Yellow Paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf):
[image]

where the symbol ∅ represents an empty set.

[Searching the go-ethereum source code for contractAddress](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=contractaddress&type=Code) shows that `getTransactionReceipt(...)` is the method to return the contract address. From [eth/api.go, lines 1083-1132](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/3885907c7deb598ed491ca4deccc562b27b31d66/eth/api.go#L1083-L1132):

```
func (s *PublicTransactionPoolAPI) GetTransactionReceipt(txHash common.Hash) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    receipt := core.GetReceipt(s.chainDb, txHash)
    if receipt == nil {
        glog.V(logger.Debug).Infof("receipt not found for transaction %s", txHash.Hex())
        return nil, nil
    }

    tx, _, err := getTransaction(s.chainDb, s.txPool, txHash)
    if err != nil {
        glog.V(logger.Debug).Infof("%v\n", err)
        return nil, nil
    }

    txBlock, blockIndex, index, err := getTransactionBlockData(s.chainDb, txHash)
    if err != nil {
        glog.V(logger.Debug).Infof("%v\n", err)
        return nil, nil
    }

    from, err := tx.FromFrontier()
    if err != nil {
        glog.V(logger.Debug).Infof("%v\n", err)
        return nil, nil
    }

    fields := map[string]interface{}{
        "root":              common.Bytes2Hex(receipt.PostState),
        "blockHash":         txBlock,
        "blockNumber":       rpc.NewHexNumber(blockIndex),
        "transactionHash":   txHash,
        "transactionIndex":  rpc.NewHexNumber(index),
        "from":              from,
        "to":                tx.To(),
        "gasUsed":           rpc.NewHexNumber(receipt.GasUsed),
        "cumulativeGasUsed": rpc.NewHexNumber(receipt.CumulativeGasUsed),
        "contractAddress":   nil,
        "logs":              receipt.Logs,
    }

    if receipt.Logs == nil {
        fields["logs"] = []vm.Logs{}
    }

    // If the ContractAddress is 20 0x0 bytes, assume it is not a contract creation
    if bytes.Compare(receipt.ContractAddress.Bytes(), bytes.Repeat([]byte{0}, 20)) != 0 {
        fields["contractAddress"] = receipt.ContractAddress
    }

    return fields, nil
}
```

Comment: I asked this question so you could answer it. I knew you would know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I have been waiting for quite a while for you to ask this exact question :-)